# How to pass model to editor templates

Tags: telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc, mvc-editor-templates

I am using Telerik MVC Grid, with ajax binding and I use grid editing in InCell editing mode with editor templates. I would like to pass model to the editors.

As I know if I had used the server binding, it could be possible to pass the model to the editor templates. But I am not sure about Ajax binding.

Is it possible to pass a model to editor templates when you use Ajax binding?

Comment: Could you elaborate more about the model you want to pass

Comment: Let's say I would like to pass List<string> as a model for a dropdown list in editor template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can! It does it automatically. just if your template editor is a list box , you should pass the list items through a ViewBag.XXX property. 
Here is an example of ProductSelector.ascx editor template :

```
    <%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<int>" %>

<%Html.Telerik().ComboBox()
        .Name(ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(string.Empty))
        .AutoFill(true)
            .BindTo(((IEnumerable<Aien.CRM.Biz.Entities.Product>)ViewBag.PossibleProducts).Select(option => new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = (option == null ? "(None)" : option.Title),
                Value = option.Id.ToString()
            }))
        .OpenOnFocus(true)
        .Render();

%>
```

don't forget to put a UiHint attribute for the related model property.

Comment: Good idea, but isn't there any other way to pass the Model to the editor template or access it from the editor template directly?

Comment: Passing the whole Model to editor template? why? you can pass it to editor template simply like what you do for "int". But if you do so, your editor template should be a editor for the whole model not just one of its properties.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16065740/85269. I also would like a method that involves being able to pass a model object directly to a template, something like a `Partial(...)` call.  However, this option does not appear to have been built into MVC, leaving `ViewBag` as the remaining option.

Answer (score 0):

There is also the new feature of Telerik Mvc Grid called: ForeignKey, that allow you to do  abstraction of the editor template and providing it simply the SelectList (or IEnumerable). [Here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/foreignkeycolumn) is an example of it.

```
columns.ForeignKey(o => o.EmployeeID, (IEnumerable)ViewData["employees"], 
                   "ID", "Name").Width(230);
```

By default it is using drop down list, you can change that by client template.